# Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio

Tags: discusión, asociación-de-preguntas

**Esta es una lista de las 45 preguntas más visitadas por gente cuyo principal lenguaje no es el inglés sino el español (según sus preferencias del browser).**

La mayoría de la gente que nos visita acude a estas preguntas primero sin visitar a nuestro sitio al terminar de leer las respuestas en el sitio de inglés.  Estamos perdiendo la oportunidad para invitar a estos visitantes a venir a nuestro sitio y a formar parte de nuestra comunidad.

La idea aquí es de presentarles a estos visitantes la opción de venir a leer respuestas a estas preguntas famosas en su propio lenguaje - el español.  Si la pregunta o la respuesta no existe, tendremos la oportunidad de publicarla.

Lo que les pido es lo siguiente. Necesito que me compartan los enlaces a preguntas similares y las publiquen como una respuesta.  Yo me encargaré de asignar los pares y de presentarles a los visitantes un mensaje demostrándoles que la respuesta a su pregunta esta en nuestro sitio. Les enseñare el enlace a nuestra pregunta y les daremos la oportunidad para visitarnos.

He aquí las Top 45 preguntas:

1. Vistas: 6725    [Converting String To Int In

   Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779)
2. Vistas: 6432    [How Do I Redirect To Another Page In    Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093)
3. Vistas: 5060    [How To Remove A Particular Element From An Array In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325)
4. Vistas: 5052    [Sql Server Case When Or Then Else End The Or Is Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5487892)
5. Vistas: 4826    [Update From Select Using Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334712)
6. Vistas: 4793    [How To Create An Html Button That Acts Like A Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2906582)
7. Vistas: 4412    [How To Split A String In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828)
8. Vistas: 3702    [No Access Control Allow Origin Header Is Present On The Requested Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101)
9. Vistas: 3514    [Set Select Option Selected By Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13343566)
10. Vistas: 3501   [Replacing All Occurrences Of A String In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783)
11. Vistas: 3418   [How To Perform An If Then In An Sql Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63447)
12. Vistas: 3397   [How To Make A Redirect In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/768431)
13. Vistas: 3137   [Setting Checked For A Checkbox With Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426258)
14. Vistas: 3070   [Java Convert Integer To String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5071040)
15. Vistas: 3046   [How To Check If A String Contains A Specific Word In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366730)
16. Vistas: 2943   [Center A Column Using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18153234)
17. Vistas: 2919   [How To Format A Javascript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461)
18. Vistas: 2917   [How To Find All Files Containing Specific Text On Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810)
19. Vistas: 2855   [How To Declare An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621)
20. Vistas: 2833   [Disable Enable An Input With Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414365)
21. Vistas: 2799   [How Do I Compare Strings In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832)
22. Vistas: 2753   [How To Undo Last Commits In Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358)
23. Vistas: 2720   [How Do I Get Php Errors To Display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424)
24. Vistas: 2703   [Horizontally Center A Div In A Div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543)
25. Vistas: 2688   [Api Ms Win Crt Runtime L1 1 0 Dll Is Missing When Open Office File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33265663)
26. Vistas: 2670   [Parse String To Float Or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379906)
27. Vistas: 2611   [How To Vertically Center Text With Css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458)
28. Vistas: 2609   [Php Notice Undefined Variable And Notice Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)
29. Vistas: 2596   [For Each Over An Array In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446)
30. Vistas: 2596   [Get Selected Value In Dropdown List Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801)
31. Vistas: 2558   [Error Message Forbidden You Dont Have Permission To Access On This Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10873295)
32. Vistas: 2531   [How Do I Check If A Checkbox Is Checked In Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901712)
33. Vistas: 2504   [How To Open A Bootstrap Modal Window Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13183630)
34. Vistas: 2485   [Generating Random Integers In A Specific Range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681)
35. Vistas: 2482   [How Can I Set The Default Value For An Html Select Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518002)
36. Vistas: 2448   [How To Check If One String Contains Another Substring In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945)
37. Vistas: 2444   [Round To At Most 2 Decimal Places In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11832914)
38. Vistas: 2410   [Xampp Apache Error Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18300377)
39. Vistas: 2300   [How To Revert Git Repository To A Previous Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095)
40. Vistas: 2280   [Vertical Align With Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547819)
41. Vistas: 2279   [Unsupported Major Minor Version 52 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22489398)
42. Vistas: 2259   [How To Determine If Variable Is Undefined Or Null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647867)
43. Vistas: 2223   [Redirect From An Html Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411538)
44. Vistas: 2208   [Get The Full Url In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793)
45. Vistas: 2201   [How Do I Install Pip On Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806)

Comment: Me gustaría ayudar, pero no sé la forma actual de trabajar. Por ahora tengo entendido de 1) Generar una pregunta con un título similar al equivalente en inlgés, 2) Responder con la solución como wiki de comunidad, 3) Editar ĺa respuesta de abajo y colocar el enlace en su sitio correspondiente, eso es todo? , no hay lineamientos especiales o algo en especial?

Comment: Creo que @EduenSarceño tiene razón en que las respuestas deberían ser wiki de comunidad. Esto abre la puerta a que se convierta en un "voy a traducir preguntas para obtener puntos" sin crecimiento orgánico real del sitio, un tema que ya se trató en el pasado en meta: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/138 http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/236 o http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/230

Answer (score 10):

#### Preguntas en español

<sup>**Wiki de comunidad, para que todos editen.**</sup>

1. Vistas: 6725    [Converting String To Int In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779)

   - Español: [Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1487/127)
2. Vistas: 6432    [How Do I Redirect To Another Page In Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093)

   - Español: [Redirección utilizando JQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20804/127)
3. Vistas: 5060    [How To Remove A Particular Element From An Array In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325)

   - Español: [¿Como eliminar un elemento especifico de un array?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45508)
   - Alternativa: [¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos en JavaScript o jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1869/127)
4. Vistas: 5052    [Sql Server Case When Or Then Else End The Or Is Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5487892)

   - Español: [Como usar CASE dentro de WHERE en SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30399/127)
5. Vistas: 4826    [Update From Select Using Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334712)

   - Español: [UPDATE desde un SELECT usando SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48596)
6. Vistas: 4793    [How To Create An Html Button That Acts Like A Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2906582)

   - Español: [¿Como crear un botón HTML que funcione como un link?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48805)
7. Vistas: 4412    [How To Split A String In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828)

   - Español: [Como separar un String en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45847/95)
8. Vistas: 3702    [No Access Control Allow Origin Header Is Present On The Requested Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101)

   - Español: ***pendiente***
   - Relacionada: [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)
   - Relacionada: [CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en Angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/35188/127)
   - Relacionada: [Necesito subir una API Rest a un servidor web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13113/127)
9. Vistas: 3514    [Set Select Option Selected By Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13343566)

   - Español: [¿Cómo setear un valor por defecto a mi select mediante jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56144/127)
10. Vistas: 3501   [Replacing All Occurrences Of A String In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783)

    - Español: [¿Cómo eliminar o reemplazar todas las subcadenas de un string en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49125/127)
11. Vistas: 3418   [How To Perform An If Then In An Sql Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63447)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
    - Relacionado: [Como usar CASE dentro de WHERE en SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30399/127) (marcada previamente)
12. Vistas: 3397   [How To Make A Redirect In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/768431)

    - Español #1: [PHP y la función header(location: )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/19791/127)
    - Español #2: [Cómo redireccionar con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8864/127)
    - Español #3: [Si me mandan una URL en el GET redirigir a esa URL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4012/127)
13. Vistas: 3137   [Setting Checked For A Checkbox With Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426258)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
    - Relacionada: [Checked radio boton. ajax php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/15411/127)
14. Vistas: 3070   [Java Convert Integer To String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5071040)

    - Español: [Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1487/127)
15. Vistas: 3046   [How To Check If A String Contains A Specific Word In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366730)

    - Español: [¿Cómo comprobar si una cadena contiene una palabra específica en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/34946/127)
16. Vistas: 2943   [Center A Column Using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18153234)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
    - Relacionada: [Cómo hacer un DIV flotante a la derecha con Twitter Bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4352/127)
17. Vistas: 2919   [How To Format A Javascript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461)

    - Español: [¿Cómo dar formato a una fecha en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49370/)
18. Vistas: 2917   [How To Find All Files Containing Specific Text On Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810)

    - Español: [Buscar todos los archivos que contienen una cadena de texto en Linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1479/127)
19. Vistas: 2855   [How To Declare An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621)

    - Español: [Arreglo tridimensional en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44612/127)
20. Vistas: 2833   [Disable Enable An Input With Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414365)

    - Español: [Habilitar y deshabilitar elemento con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/91965/14088)
21. Vistas: 2799   [How Do I Compare Strings In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832)

    - Español: [¿Cómo comparar correctamente Strings en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225/127)
22. Vistas: 2753   [How To Undo Last Commits In Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358)

    - Español: [¿Cómo puedo deshacer el último commit en Git?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90/127)
23. Vistas: 2720   [How Do I Get Php Errors To Display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424)

    - Español: [Hablitar errores en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18401/127)
24. Vistas: 2703   [Horizontally Center A Div In A Div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543)

    - Español #1: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre position: relative, position: absolute y position: fixed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/37930/127)
    - Español #2: [¿Cómo puedo centrar horizontalmente un div dentro de otro div?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103/127)
25. Vistas: 2688   [Api Ms Win Crt Runtime L1 1 0 Dll Is Missing When Open Office File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33265663)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
26. Vistas: 2670   [Parse String To Float Or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379906)

    - Español: [¿Cómo convertir un tipo String a Float o Int?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49194/83)
27. Vistas: 2611   [How To Vertically Center Text With Css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458)

    - Español: [Alineación vertical central con CSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49020/)
28. Vistas: 2609   [Php Notice Undefined Variable And Notice Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)

    - Español: [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, y “Notice: Undefined offset” ¿Qué quiere decir?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79165/29967)
29. Vistas: 2596   [For Each Over An Array In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446)

    - Español: [For each en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17640/127)
30. Vistas: 2596   [Get Selected Value In Dropdown List Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801)

    - Español: [Mostrar lo que se seleccione de un](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/28048/127)
31. Vistas: 2558   [Error Message Forbidden You Dont Have Permission To Access On This Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10873295)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
32. Vistas: 2531   [How Do I Check If A Checkbox Is Checked In Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901712)

    - Español: [Validar un Checkbox con JQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6657/127)
33. Vistas: 2504   [How To Open A Bootstrap Modal Window Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13183630)

    - Español: ***pendiente***
    - Relacionada: [Abrir una ventana modal de bootstrap con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43484/127) **[cerrada]**
    - Relacionada: [Modal de Bootstrap no se abre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20731/127)
34. Vistas: 2485   [Generating Random Integers In A Specific Range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681)

    - Español: [¿Como generar números aleatorios dentro de un rango de valores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5390/como-generar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-dentro-de-un-rango-de-valores)
35. Vistas: 2482   [How Can I Set The Default Value For An Html Select Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518002)

    - Español: [Seleccionar un valor por defecto en un elemento HTML  cuya opción está deshabilitada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48900/127)
36. Vistas: 2448   [How To Check If One String Contains Another Substring In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945)

    - Español: [Validar si un texto contiene una subcadena en JavaScript o jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/14590/127)
37. Vistas: 2444   [Round To At Most 2 Decimal Places In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11832914)

    - Español: [Redondear a dos decimales cuando sea necesario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48958/)
38. Vistas: 2410   [Xampp Apache Error Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18300377)

    - Español: [Apache con XAMPP no inicia por puertos bloqueados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19703/apache-con-xampp-no-inicia-por-puertos-bloqueados)
39. Vistas: 2300   [How To Revert Git Repository To A Previous Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095)

    - Español: [Regresar un repositorio a un commit especifico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1458/127)
40. Vistas: 2280   [Vertical Align With Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547819)

    - Español: [¿Como puedo alinear verticalmente un contenido de un div con bootstrap 3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48940/127)
41. Vistas: 2279   [Unsupported Major Minor Version 52 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22489398)

    - Español: [Error “Unsupported major.minor version” en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/178/127)
42. Vistas: 2259   [How To Determine If Variable Is Undefined Or Null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647867)

    - Español: [Cómo determinar si una variable es 'undefined' o 'null' en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49109/)
43. Vistas: 2223   [Redirect From An Html Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411538)

    - Español: [¿Cómo redirigir una página con HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48357/83)
44. Vistas: 2208   [Get The Full Url In Php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793)

    - Español: [¿Cómo obtener la URL completa en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49890/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-url-completa-en-php)
45. Vistas: 2201   [How Do I Install Pip On Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806)

    - Español: [Como instalo PIP en Windows?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48590)

Comment: ¿El propósito con las preguntas cruzadas que están en estado pendiente en español es cuál? ¿preguntarlas o traducir las que están en SOen?

Comment: @dwarandae Muy buena pregunta....la verdad no lo se.  Creo es para que otros vayan contestando la pregunta específicamente sin tener otras preguntas relacionadas. ¡Gracias a Mariano por empezar la búsqueda! Puse las ultimas como pendientes por la misma razón pero para que se viera que faltan respuestas todavía.

Comment: Gran trabajo, Mariano. Me permito añadir una que acabo de publicar en modo CW.

Comment: Gracias... ¡Esa es la idea @fedorqui, que todos agreguen! Es para que todos contribuyan (incluso puede haber alguna que no haya encontrado y sea mejor de lo que publiqué).

Comment: ok @Mariano la estoy traduciendo literarmente igual.

Comment: @Mariano no hay problema. Prefiero que sean literales ya que sabemos que estan probadas y aprobadas por la comunidad. Si la reescribo a mi parecer, capaz cometo algun error (hasta involuntario).

Comment: Acá tratando de contribuir con la número 10 http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49125/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-o-reemplazar-todas-las-subcadenas-de-un-string-en-javascript/

Comment: Para la pregunta 20 he creado esta que es una traducción literal: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/91965/14088 y he encontrado una relacionada en SO Es https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/29704/14088