# Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes

Tags: discusión, asociación-de-preguntas

Desde ya mismo está disponible la asociación de preguntas entre Stack Overflow [en inglés] y Stack Overflow en español.

#### ¿Qué quiere decir asociación de preguntas?

Que si una persona con el navegador configurado en castellano entra en una pregunta de Stack Overflow que tiene una pregunta equivalente en Stack Overflow en español, verá en la parte inferior un mensaje del tipo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es, un texto que dice:

> Esta pregunta también tiene respuestas en Stack Overflow en español: [Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1487/83)
>
> <sub>ejemplo con [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779/1983854) y su equivalente [Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1487/83)</sub>

#### ¿Cuál es el objetivo de la asociación?

Al crearse de las comunidades Stack Overflow específicos (portugués, japonés, ruso y español) se ha ido fortaleciendo la presencia de comunidades Stack Overflow en distintos idiomas, estableciendo comunidades potentes pero probablemente desconectadas entre ellas.

Con la asociación de preguntas se permite acortar la distancia entre estas comunidades, permitiendo saltar de la inglesa a la española para problemas concretos, facilitando que los programadores encuentren soluciones en su idioma. Además, añade una vía de entrada de usuarios hispanohablantes en nuestra comunidad.

#### ¿Cómo puede sugerirse una asociación?

Si detectas una pregunta en SOes que es equivalente a otra de SO de especial relevancia, añade un comentario a la pregunta con el formato:

> asociación: `<enlace a la página en SO>`

Es decir, la palabra "asociación" seguida de dos puntos, un espacio y la URL. Por ejemplo:

> asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java

Después de la URL se puede poner un comentario para que el OP sepa de qué va todo esto :)

Periódicamente, el CM [Nicolas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky) lanzará una consulta a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) para encontrar estos comentarios y proceder a realizar el mapeo entre preguntas en SO y SOes.

#### Me encanta. ¿Por dónde empiezo?

Puedes ir a [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/83) y:

- detectar aquellas preguntas que no tengan equivalente en SO. Puedes realizar un equivalente en SOes siguiendo la guía [¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english).
- añadir el comentario de marras a las preguntas que ya se ha detectado que tienen su equivalente.

¡Demos las gracias a Juan M por la publicación de hace dos años en que nos descubrió esta gran herramienta a los usuarios de SOes y a Nicolas por idear e implementar esta fantástica idea!

<sub>Publicación basada en [An association of questions between sites is available! de MetaSOru](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/193685).</sub>

Comment: Perfecto! Esto sería obligatorio añadirlo en preguntas canónicas traducidas de SO? Actualmente ponemos el enlace de "pregunta original"

Comment: Me parece muy interesante esta posibilidad. Si hacemos el trabajo de asociar estas preguntas, es muy probable que aumente el numero de visitas a SOes. Yo me apunto a asociar las que vaya viendo por ahi :)

Comment: Me surge una duda. Iba ahora mismo a asociar un par de preguntas canónicas que tengo en el sitio:https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/76861 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999. El problema es que la pregunta original tiene 2 etiquetas:[tag:c#] y [tag:vb.net]. Sin embargo yo al traducir las respuestas lo separé en dos preguntas diferentes. Se puede asociar una pregunta en SO a dos preguntas en SOes?

Comment: @Pikoh que Nicolas me corrija si me equivoco, pero actualmente la relación es 1:1 entre preguntas de SO y de SOes. Yo le pregunté por este caso y [me dijo que no](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49236672#49236672), si bien no sé si internamente solamente apuntaría a una, o simplemente fallaría. Invoquémosle para que nos saque de dudas : )

Comment: @lois6b obligatorio, obligatorio... no. Pero sería genial hacerlo. Nicolas dijo que [en SOru tienen más de 500 asociadas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49041706#49041706), lo que nos da buena muestra de la cantidad de asociaciones que podemos llegar a hacer.

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, ahí te dice claramente que en principio no es posible. En este caso, asociaré una y como en esa tengo un enlace a la otra, pues esperemos que sea claro.

Comment: Tras la asociación y mapeo, el comentario sigue siendo necesario o se borra/puede borrarse ?^^

Comment: @lois6b no creo, eo comentario es una vía de entrada pero no debería necesitar estar sincronizada con la lista de mapeos, más que nada porque genera ruido

Comment: ¿Funciona solo en el sitio principal o también en meta?

Answer (score 2):

Esta página necesita ser actualizada: [Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Entiendo, corregidme si no es así, que la asociación que establece Nicolás permanece incluso después del borrado del comentario. Si así fuese podría ser buena idea borrar el comentario ya que no es una *aclaración* ni una *crítica constructiva*. Sí se puede considerar *información menor o temporal*, pero temporal significa precisamente eso, que desaparecerá.

Estaría bien que el usuario que puso el comentario recibiese una notificación al respecto cuando se haga efectiva la asociación. Evitamos así una "espera ocupada". Pero, considerando que el proceso es manual, imagino que esto no es así ahora.

Felicito a Nicolás por esta iniciativa. Sirva lo anterior como sugerencias a lo que me parece un paso en una buena dirección.

Comment: Sí, la asociación permanece tras borrar el comentario. También yo supuse que el comentario podría borrarse, pero [Nicolas comenta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49273217#49273217) que mejor no, pues no hay otra manera de saber si una pregunta está asociada. Debatamos cuál podría ser la mejor opción (aquí, en el chat The Terminal o en Github).

Comment: Yo propuse que en la pregunta de SOes salga un mensaje parecido al que sale en SO, diciendo algo tipo "esta pregunta tiene su equivalencia en SO: url", que podría ser útil.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez es muy pronto para discutir esto pero para no que se me olvide, les comparto que me pregunto

- qué pasará si varias preguntas son asociadas a la misma pregunta en inglés, en esta ¿se mostrará sólo un enlace o se incluirán varios enlaces?
- qué pasará si se reportan los comentarios de asociación para ser eliminados sin considerar esta iniciativa.

  - Esto ya se ha mencionado en comentarios a la pregunta, pero aún no me queda claro, será cosa de releer y participar en La Terminal / proyecto de GitHub.
  - Quizás en el corto plazo lo más sencillo será volver a agregar los comentarios eliminados y para prevenir tener que hacer esto si estamos de acuerdo con una asociación, deberíamos votarla positivo.
- qué pasará si una pregunta tiene varios comentarios de asociación, ya sea a la misma pregunta o a preguntas diferentes

  - [Alineación vertical central con CSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49020/65) (este tiene una asociación agregada desde la herramienta web y otra agregada directamente a la pregunta, ambas a la misma pregunta)

---

Asociaciones que he realizado

- [Convertir reporte tabular (matriz) a formato de tabla simple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6091/65)
- [¿Cómo dar formato a una fecha en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49370/65)
- [Redondear a dos decimales cuando sea necesario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48958/65)
- [Habilitar y deshabilitar elemento con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/91965/65)
- [¿Cómo puedo extraer una cadena de caracteres con JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108475/65)
- [For each en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17640/65)

Comment: La lista de asociaciones no sé si vale la pena mantenerla viva, pues será difícil mantenerla sincronizada. En cualquier caso, de quererse yo sería del parecer de hacerlo en la pregunta original de Juan M [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/83)

Comment: En cuanto a las dudas, añadí una pregunta-respuesta en la que podemos ir respondiéndonoslas: [¿Cómo funciona la asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967/83)

Comment: @fedorqui No es mi intención mantener la lista de asociaciones viva o allá, en cualquier caso, gracias por la observación así como por la pregunta-respuesta.