# ¿Qué puedo hacer para mejorar las vistas de mis preguntas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

He hecho varias preguntas pero algunas tienen pocas vistas. Cuando las hice pensé que además de servirme a mí le servirían a otros pero pasa el tiempo y continúan con pocas vistas.

Primero pensé simplemente me había equivocado, en cuanto a que les serviría a otros, pero veo que en otros espacios preguntan lo mismo mencionando que han "googleado" pero no encontrado nada, les he compartido el enlace correspondiente y me lo han agradecido indicando que la que la respuesta a mi pregunta les ha sido de utilidad.

Algunos ejemplos de mis preguntas con menos de 200 vistas y 2 años o más de haber sido publicadas:

- [¿Cómo establecer una fecha de expiración de acceso a un archivo en Google Drive a partir de un plazo establecido en días?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/248323/65) (17 vistas)
- [¿Cómo puedo obtener la lista de mensajes enviados en Gmail?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/62806/65) (114 vistas)

Ejemplo más reciente

- [¿Es posible incluir un cuenta atrás en el cuerpo de un mensaje de correo eletrónico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/255147/65) (17 de abril, 24 vistas)

¿Qué puedo hacer para ayudar a que mis preguntas sean encontradas más fácilmente y de paso ganar alguna de las medallas por vistas a las preguntas?

Artículos de ayuda relacionados

- [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Medallas relacionadas

- [Pregunta popular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question)
- [Pregunta destacada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question)
- [Pregunta famosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)

Answer (score 1):

**La regla de oro es que el contenido es rey**.

Aunque tu pregunta ya haya sido respondida puedes mejorar su contenido cuidando de no cambiar el sentido original principalmente por respeto a quienes ya te han han aportado buenas respuestas.

Si ya tiene buenas respuestas las cuales servirían para otros casos, considera agregar esos casos a la pregunta de tal forma se vuelva una pregunta canónica.

Por ejemplo, tal vez has escrito la pregunta usando una forma de hablar poco usual, usando formas que son usuales en tu localidad pero no en Internet o el caso es demasiado específico y/o difícil de entender.

También podría ser que usas apropiadamente el argot del lenguaje pero el público que habla así usa otros espacios, como podría ser Stack Overflow (el sitio en inglés) y deberías "bajarle dos rayitas" para llegar a quienes buscan en español, es decir, mira cómo redactan las preguntas que has encontrado en otros espacios e incorpora ese lenguaje.

Luego de la redacción de la pregunta considera también mejorar el título y asegúrate que tu pregunta está etiquetada apropiadamente.

Otra alternativa es mejorar las respuestas respetando la intención original de los autores de las mismas y si aún no lo has hecho aporta tu propia respuesta considerando lo dicho arriba.

Quizás te sirvan de inspiración las preguntas famosas: [Preguntas famosas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)

**Asociación de preguntes de Stack Overflow**

También podría ayudar asociar tu pregunta a una pregunta similar en el sitio en inglés. Para más detalles consulta [Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/65).