# ¿Cómo atraer mas atención a mis preguntas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Hola a todos hago esta publicación ya que recientemente hice una publicación la cual di toda la información necesaria, la hice en los foros que yo creo buenos y ofrecí una recompensa por la pregunta pero aun así nadie se ha fijado en mi pregunta, ya paso mas 4 días desde la recompensa y solo ha ganado creo que 4 o 3 visitas, [esta es la publicacion en stackoverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493349/no-se-pudo-entrar-en-la-carpeta-tags) y [esta es la publicacion en unix y linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676035/kde-neon-spanish-error-no-se-pudo-entrar-en-la-carpeta-tags) (quiero aclarar que no espero que me respondan en ese mismo momento solo pregunto ¿cómo puedo llamar la atención a mis preguntas?)

### Edit

Hice este edit debido a que como mencione arriba mis preguntas no recibieron respuesta e incluso ya caduco mi recompensa, por lo que pregunto, ¿puedo hacer otra pregunta con el mismo tema, por decirlo asi una pregunta duplicada? Gracias a todos desde ya

Comment: Generalmente uno tiene que esperar bastante para recibir una respuesta que sea la que necesitas. La verdad lo estás haciendo bien con el tema de usar las recompensas y eso, no sabría decirte si necesites algo mas.

Comment: A veces simplemente hay pocas personas que conozcan específicamente sobre eso.

Comment: Relacionado https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4100/65

Comment: La pregunta, la han revisado alrededor de 100 veces, y solo una ha aparecido tratando de responder. Simplemente no hay gente que conozca el tema o el problema. Te recomiendo buscar en sitios en inglés, aunque sea más dificil el tener que traducir.

Comment: @Excorpion esta bien, buscare en esos sitios

Comment: En relación "al edit", no es aceptable publicar la misma pregunta una segunda vez.

Comment: @Rubén ok, gracias :(

Comment: @Emeeus no necesariamente; la pregunta que hizo en el sitio en español es Off-Topic y esta mal planteada: no incluye la Versión ni la Distro de linux y ya conocemos la amalgama que existen ... puede haber una respuesta distinta para cada una de ellas; y lo mas importante el off-topic, ***en SOes no resolvemos problema de Sistema Operativos*** que no estén relacionadas a un código de programación y un problema especifico.

Comment: por ejemplo: si a pregunta fuera sobre ***HASKEL y el despliegue de un menú** con ***código fuente*** ... para el SO Kali Linux de seguro que seria bien recibida ya que cumple con las normas del sitio; en la cual hay un lenguaje de programación y un código relacionado que esta teniendo un problema ...

Comment: Incluso si hay personas expertas en el tema aquí: pero no es el sitio adecuado para hacer la pregunta ... y estas personas que saben del tema tambien saben que preguntas se deben responder y cuales se deben cerrar.

Comment: en resumen el problema no es solamente el contenido; si no tambien seguir las normas del sitio.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent literalmente, escribí ABSOLUTAMENTE toda la información acerca de mi pregunta, ya casi no se puede dar mas informacion. Saludos

Comment: te acabo de decir que informacion te hace falta ... para que yo te pueda dar una solucion.

Answer (score 3):

Hola atraer atención a tus preguntas es un arma de doble filo; ya que aunque lo logres, la percepción que tenga la comunidad en general de tu POST puede ser positiva o negativa... y de esa misma manera comenzaran a evaluar tu POST.

***Existen dos puntos de suma importancia para evaluar un POST y Atraer Personas:***

**1. Seguir las Normas del Sitio:**

Como lo decía en los comentarios, un post que siga las normas del sitio y cumpla con lo que la comunidad solicite será bien recibido; incluso en el [canal de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) puedes pedir ayuda y concejo al respecto y no crear post que te perjudiquen.

Por ese motivo es importante recalcar a todo los usuario que lean los artículos:

- [Recorrido.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [Temas Aceptados.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Temas no Aceptados.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [Como Elaborar Una Buena Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [El Uso de los Comentarios.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

y evitar esto:

- [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo)

**2. El Contenido del POST:**

Como lo explica el compañero [Ruben](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%C3%A9n) en su [POST de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4101/46896).

**Evaluando el POST:**
[No se pudo entrar en la carpeta tags:/](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493349/no-se-pudo-entrar-en-la-carpeta-tags)

- El contenido de tu POST no forma parte de los temas Aceptados.
- El contenido de tu POST no incluye una Manera de Reproducir el Error o Problema.
- No cumples con las normas del sitio de como elaborar una buena pregunta.
- En el momento que yo te solicite mayor informacion te obviaste darla, argumentando que el contexto de tu pregunta se ubicaba en un solo escenario cuando pueden haber múltiples.

En teoría has tenido suerte; la comunidad ha tenido interés en tu pregunta recibiendo votos positivos aunque claramente es un problema de una aplicación o bug; y queda ubicado como **off-topic**.

Por este motivo y los anteriores es posible que no hayas obtenido una respuesta.

**Tu siguiente pregunta fue:** *¿puedo hacer otra pregunta con el mismo tema, por decirlo asi una pregunta duplicada?*

**Respuesta: *No.***